# determining the correct type of exceptions

Tags: haskell, monads

(Newbie question. :-) )

Suppose you have a sequence of operations (sanity checks on the outside world). If sanity fails, one has to holler.

However, Haskell ifs require both branches be defined. The case of `fail` is a monad. However, I'm unsure what the correct type to generate in the else case. The compiler thinks the inferred type is IO a. However, I'm not sure how to create an no-op IO a.

```
holler msg test =  
  do
    if not test 
      then
      fail msg
      else
      -- ??? no-op

main :: IO ()
main = do
  holler "Go" True
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest thing is to `return ()`. There are some handy functions that do that part for you, namely `when` and `unless`; your example is simply `holler msg test = unless test (fail msg)`.

Comment: Huh, okay. I'm getting a "not in scope" error for when & unless, and Google's not helping me. I presume its in a library?

Comment: @Paul: `import Control.Monad`, or for next time, [ask Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=unless).

Comment: Yes, import `Control.Monad`. In the future, [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/) ([example one](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?q=unless), [example two](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=Monad+m+%3D%3E+Bool+-%3E+m+%28%29+-%3E+m+%28%29)) is the preferred search engine for Haskell functions.

Answer (score 9):

The inferred type is `IO a` because `fail msg` may return anything (since it does in fact never return). However the else part doesn't actually have to produce an `IO a`, it's perfectly fine to make it into something more specific, i.e. `IO WhateverYouWant`.

In this case you don't care about the return value, so you should just use `IO ()`, i.e. put `return ()` in the `else` case.

And as it turns out there's already a function called `when condition action` in the `Control.Monad` module, which does exactly `if condition then action else return ()`, so you can just use that one (or its counterpart `unless`, which negates the condition saving you the `not`) instead of typing out the `if`.